# Github | why when i push to specific branch does not recorded in my contributions

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I've create a project with many branches in a private repo, and i am currently working with specific branch called  `Mp6-The-Three-Cup-Shuffle`

i pushed many times my commits into the branch but none of them was recorded in my contributions graph.

i already removed everything inside the folder and then re-create the packages again, however the folder and the remote still the same, i didn't need to use  `git checkout Mp6-The-Three-Cup-Shuffle`. would that effect?

***I've checked my username and my email and they already configured.***

[image]

***also i can see my commits have been pushed and the changes are already in the github***

[image]

***but none of that was recorded like in the contribution image explains,***

[image]

any suggestions can help explaining why this doesn't work? and how can i make it works?

***NOTE:*** i am pushing everything from IntelliJ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GitHub is counting only contributions to the *default* and *gh-pages* branches.

Here's a quote from [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/):

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet **all** of
>   the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub    account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork. The    commits were made:
> - In the repository's default branch (usually `master`)
> - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with [Project Pages sites](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages-sites))

Keep in mind that when working with private repos, you have to allow GitHub to show your private contributions:

[image]

However, contributions graph will not state which pricate repos are you working on:

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: How in hell i didn't noticed that, so i guess if i want to fix it i have to make my branch as default branch, right ?

Comment: We'll depends how your project is structured when it comes to git. If you are going to merge your branch into the default, you will be credited for contributions after the merge. :)

Comment: i find it helpful already, but still waiting if someone can answer me with a full explanation about it. otherwise i will mark it as accepted later on :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that if you merge your branch into the master or default branch then it will populate on the graph for those commit pushes.